# Please can someone help tell me what my independent variables and dependent variables should be?

Tags: variables

This study aims to examine the following relationships: between proper use of intermittent treated net (ITNs) and malaria prevalence among children under five, between education and proper use of antimalarial drugs, between healthcare preference and malaria outcome during pregnancy, and finally, between socioeconomic status and healthcare seeking behavior among rural community members.

Comment: ...how is this related to software development? I suggest you take the [tour] and learn [ask]

Comment: Or it maybe something on your notebook..

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I think is a space one can ask questions of any type and I think if you're knowledgeable you should share. I was having difficulties so that is why I asked.

Comment: Not sure but try .. http://health.stackexchange.com/ .. But you need to still improve your question..

Answer (score -2):

Your independent variables appear to be:
Proper use of ITNs
Education
Healthcare preference
Socio-economic status

Comment: Thank you and what about the dependent variables.

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that are not on-topic for this site.